# Which version of android will let me access photos taken by my phone?

Tags: android, photo-gallery

I am developing an app that will let users attach a picture to some text within the app itself but the user will need to access the phones gallery to pull photos out of it and into the application. My phone is running 2.3.5 is this version capable?? Can't seem to find a definitive answer on the net!! Thanks guys.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose images from Gallery,

```
public class SelectPhotoActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE); 
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
           // here you can set the image
            }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely capable of retrieving images from gallery. Can you post your code, how you are trying to get images from Gallery?